# unsupported CodecID V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC ffmpeg Centos 6.8

Tags: video, ffmpeg, centos, hevc, mkv

i have tried to convert an mkv video file with ffmpeg on centos 6.8 but i keep getting this error `Unknown/unsupported CodecID V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC`

```
MediaInfo:
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L4@Main
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
```

how can i install this codecs on my OS and proceed with the convertion of the video!?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this ffmpeg build is rather old and has no HEVC/h265 support. To decode h265 video, you have to build a new ffmpeg with libx265 or download a version with bundled libx265. Like this http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: You only need libx265 for encoding. Decoding support for HEVC is built-in by default.